# How to create a search bar for images and text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, searchbar

I want to create a search bar that filters out divs from the page.
I have attempted to create one but it only filters out the text from the div and makes the image disappear.

My Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#articleSearchInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#card *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="articleSearchInput" placeholder="Search For Blalala......">

<div class="card mt-4" id="card">
        <div class="card-body">

        <img src="myimgpath" id="articleImage" alt="loremipsum0" />

        <p class="card-title">Blalala</p>

        <div class="card-text mb-2" id="cardDescription">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>

<div class="card mt-4" id="card">
        <div class="card-body">

        <img src="myimgpath" id="articleImage" alt="loremipsum1" />

        <p class="card-title">Blalala</p>

        <div class="card-text mb-2" id="cardDescription">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>

<div class="card mt-4" id="card">
        <div class="card-body">

        <img src="myimgpath" id="articleImage" alt="loremipsum2" />

        <p class="card-title">Blalala</p>

        <div class="card-text mb-2" id="cardDescription">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>
```

Is there any way I can make this search bar work with both images and text at the same time?
Thanks In Advance.
Please let me know if I have to add any more info in the question.

Comment: What do you mean as images ?

Comment: Do you mean find image while texting ?

Comment: Hey! I meant that the search bar in the above code only indexes the given text, and ignores the image tag. Please help to make it index both text and images

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

I don't know if you noticed but you're lacking end divs on every card so I added it first then I change the values of your card title to bala, bolo, bili in order to check each cards that they differ from each other then I added this line of code:
 
     `if (value == "bala") { $("#articleImage1").show(); }`
that says, If value is equal to "bala" (which is your card title) then I will show the image element with the `$("#articleImage1").show();`

It's up to you now how can you manipulate other values.

```js
var val = $.trim(this.value);
if (val === "")
  $('img').show();
else {
  $('img').hide();
  $("img[alt*=" + val + "]").show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#articleSearchInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#card *").filter(function() {

      if (value == "bala") {
        $("#articleImage1").show();
      }
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="articleSearchInput" placeholder="Search For Blalala......">

<div class="card mt-4" id="card">

    <div class="card-body">

      <img src="myimgpath" id="articleImage1" alt="loremipsum0" />

      <p class="card-title">bala</p>

      <div class="card-text mb-2" id="cardDescription">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>



<div class="card mt-4" id="card">

    <div class="card-body">

      <img src="myimgpath" id="articleImage" alt="loremipsum1" />

      <p class="card-title">bolo</p>

      <div class="card-text mb-2" id="cardDescription">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>



<div class="card mt-4" id="card">

    <div class="card-body">

      <img src="myimgpath" id="articleImage" alt="loremipsum2" />

      <p class="card-title">bili</p>

      <div class="card-text mb-2" id="cardDescription">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```